# keyword definition not found in robot framework

Tags: robotframework, keyword

I have a windows 7 laptop and a windows 10 desktop and I install both with robot framework. In the laptop, all goes well.  I was successfully able to create and run test, keywords suggestions is doing great, etc.. but with my desktop, the auto suggestion does not display the suggested keywords and i am always having a Keyword definition not found error. I have intellibot installed and it goes well in my laptop. Project interpreter for both computers are the same. exactly the same.

Comment: If you have these error the your installation on desktop messes something.

Comment: This issue was solved by reverting robotframework-selenium2library to 1.8.0 version.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Recently the `SeleniumLibrary` introduced some internal architectural changes that caused the keyword autosuggestion feature in the `IntelliJ`/`PyCharm` `IntelliBot` plugin to stop working. This is why downgrading `SeleniumLibrary` to `Selenium2Library` version `1.8.0` works to enable autocompletion again.

As the `IntelliBot` plugin is no longer under active development, there is no expectation that this support will be enabled again in the near future. On [RoboCon 2018](https://robocon.io/) the company [Smart Dev](http://www.smddev.com) presented their IntelliJ Robot Framework extension [[slides](http://www.smddev.com/blog/events-robocon), [video](https://youtu.be/xb1Udosom6o?t=1280)]. They are currently evaluating how to make this available. If this is the platform of choice for you, then contact them.

Comment: thank you, I had the same issue and changing the version to 1.8.0 helped and I am using Robot Framework Support plugin, not intellibot, but probably same issue occurs there as well

Answer (score 3):

Yes this worked Install Robot Framework Support Plugin in your Pycharm
Go to **Setting >> Plugins>> Search as Robot Framework Support >> click on Install and Restart Pycharm**
You are good then. Happy  Testing

Comment: This is what helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. But the solution worked for me is given below:

1. Go to File -> settings-> project.
2. Click on "Add interpreter".
3. Choose the environment by Checking the 'Existing' radio button.
4. Provide path of python.exe file.
5. Click "ok".

[image]